# Share in google using GTLServicePlus with GIDAuthentication

Tags: ios, google-plus

Everything works before..

But now that i'm using the new using `GoogleSignIn.framework` to avoid rejection from apple..

---

[image]

---

How can i convert `GIDAuthentication` to `GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol`/`GTMOAuth2Authentication` to be able to use the `GPPNativeShareBuilder`?

**Update**

Sorry for the late update, I successfully created `GTMFetcherAuthorizationProtocol`/`GTMOAuth2Authentication`

Using something similar to the answer below by: *@Andr3a88* i tried his answer and it is working..

But still, I cannot use `GPPNativeShareBuilder` for sharing without authenticating using `GPPSignIn`, here is the error log:

```
[xxx/0x111533310] [lvl=3] -[GPPNativeShareBuilderImpl open] User must be signed in to use the native sharebox.
```

The alternative solution that we did was using the `GPPSignIn` and creating a custom alertview that informs the user that:

**"He is about the leave the application"** and asks for the users confirmation..

But too bad we cannot submit the app just soon, we've have decided to continue the development then go back to this if our solution wont work and worst possible option is removing G+ sharing...

If you have a solution that allows `GPPNativeShareBuilder` to work with `GIDSignIn`, your help will be very appreciated..

**Update 2**

> Adding custom alertview that asks for users confirmation that he's
>   about to leave the application did the work and approved by apple.
>   Cheers! :)

Comment: I have the same problem. My app was rejected because during login opens safari instead a webview inside the app. After fix this problem with *GIDSign* I cannot make any calls to Google+ without an authentication object type *GTMOAuth2Authentication*

Comment: Anyone got solution for this issue?

Comment: Any body got solution for this?

Comment: Hi 0yeoj I have the same problem,


I've added google sign-in and google-client-api-ios to use both client and server.


I tried the solution of @Andre3a88 but I got 


Duplicate interface definition for class 'GTMSessionFetcherUserDefaultsFactory'


And I can't get out of this problem!!!


Can you post your solution?


Thanks in advanced!

Comment: The problem is when I import #import <GTMOAuth2Authentication.h> both in AppDelegate and in the file where I use the Auth object..

Comment: @0yeoj got any solution for this????

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0, we just removed google+ sharing... but current using `GPPSignIn`...

Comment: ok .. I don't know how to get friends with gidsignin ... any way thanks

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0, that current version is quite limited... Welcome...

Comment: yes ... I know .. but need confirmation so just asked you :)

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0: Sure, but if ever you find something even if it's `hacky` please let us know... ;)

Comment: sure ... will do...

Comment: got the solution ... you can check my answer

Answer (score 4):

Actually it's quite handy to use google+ APIs with Google sign in.

For GTLServicePlus setAuthorizer, you just need use the following way to get a valid parameter:
[plusService setAuthorizer:[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].currentUser.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer];

Comment: Nope, this doesn't worked... I tried it again just now. `GPPNativeShareBuilder` is deprecated now, we removed G+ sharing though.

Comment: Worked for me. Not using plus though, using Google Drive query.

Answer (score 2):

Try in this way:

Add to your AppDelegate (or wherever you want) the following property

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) GTMOAuth2Authentication *authGooglePlus;
```

Then inside *didSignInForUser* call **setAuthorizerForSignIn**, this method is used to create *GTMOAuth2Authentication* object which will then be used for G+ api calls

```swift
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (error)
        NSLog(@"Status: G+ Authentication error: %@", error);

    [self setAuthorizerForSignIn:signIn user:user];
}

//Add this method used to create GTMOAuth2Authentication
- (void)setAuthorizerForSignIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn user:(GIDGoogleUser *)user {
    //Create GTMOAuth2Authentication
    GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = [[GTMOAuth2Authentication alloc] init];
    [auth setClientID:signIn.clientID];
    [auth setClientSecret:[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"GoogleClientSecret"]];
    [auth setUserEmail:user.profile.email];
    [auth setUserID:user.userID];
    [auth setAccessToken:user.authentication.accessToken];
    [auth setRefreshToken:user.authentication.refreshToken];
    [auth setExpirationDate: user.authentication.accessTokenExpirationDate];

    //Get app delegate and set GTMOAuth2Authentication
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.authGooglePlus = auth;
}
```

Now when you make the G+ api call sets the *GTMOAuth2Authentication* object created during the login

```
    //Get GTMOAuth2Authentication
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    GTMOAuth2Authentication * authGooglePlus = appDelegate.authGooglePlus;
    GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init];
    plusService.fetcherService.timeout = 30.0;
    [plusService authGooglePlus];
    GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"];
    [plusService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, id object, NSError *error) {

        if (error)
        {
            if(error.code ==  -1001)
            {
                 //Timeout error
            }
        }
        else
        {
             //Do something with your user
        }
}];
```

Comment: Hi Andre,  in Do something with your user 
how do I get user's gender and birthdate? Please guide me. As GIDGoogleUser don't have that field.

Comment: You should use *GTLPlusPerson* but is deprecated and moreover many people hide that information from the profile... *GIDGoogleUser* doesn't have the information you want because Google doesn't want you to give! More info: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/people

Comment: Better use `user.authentication.fetcherAuthorizer()` instead of setting all the properties yourself.

Answer (score 1):

After some search, I found that we can use Rest API to get google+ friends along with GIDSignIn ... Just you need to give scopes with GIDSignIn like below:

```
GIDSignIn *signin = [GIDSignIn sharedInstance];
signin.shouldFetchBasicProfile = true;
signin.scopes = @[@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",@"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me"];
signin.delegate = self;
signin.uiDelegate = self;
[signin signIn];
```

Than to get the friend list you need to send GET request to`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/people/collection` or `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/userId/people/collection` along with google signIn access token.

check this [Reference of google+ APIs](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/people/list) and

also check [Tutorial reference from appcoda](https://www.appcoda.com/google-sign-in-how-to/)

If you want to share than

```
- (void)showGooglePlusShare:(NSURL*)shareURL {

  // Construct the Google+ share URL
  NSURLComponents* urlComponents = [[NSURLComponents alloc]
      initWithString:@"https://plus.google.com/share"];
  urlComponents.queryItems = @[[[NSURLQueryItem alloc]
      initWithName:@"url"
             value:[shareURL absoluteString]]];
  NSURL* url = [urlComponents URL];

  if ([SFSafariViewController class]) {
    // Open the URL in SFSafariViewController (iOS 9+)
    SFSafariViewController* controller = [[SFSafariViewController alloc]
        initWithURL:url];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
  } else {
    // Open the URL in the device's browser
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
  }
}
```

Reference: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/share/basic-share